# Returning Value from inside NgRx Select

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Seems a simple question but I am new to RxJs. How do I return the value from a store subscription so that it is not an observable but the actual value?

I am calling this function which needs to return a boolean.

```js
this.checkMemberIsNotPremium(memberId)
```

Which calls the store with the memberId

```js
private checkMemberIsNotPremium(memberId): boolean {
    const memberIsNotPremium = this.store
      .pipe(select(getSelectedMemberType(), {id: memberId}))
      .subscribe((val: any) => {
        if (val.membershipType !== 'Premium') {
          return true
        } else {
        return false
        }
      });
      return memberIsNotPremium 
  }
```

I am getting a type error on the final return saying

> Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Comment: Where do you need to use the value after that?

Comment: The only way around this that I can see is to use `subjects` in which that could be set inside your subscription, then later call `getValue()` on your subject to return the object / value.

Comment: @AmerYousuf the return boolean is used to set a flag which is part of another function with different conditionals which ultimately evaluate for an *ngIf in the html.

Comment: Could you please include the code that you want to use this boolean within it?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to approach this. I always have a utility function for this which uses the RxJS operator `take(1)`:

```js
export function takeOne<T>(o: Observable<T>): T {
  let val: T
  o.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((v) => {
    val = v
  })
  return val
}

const memberId = takeOne(
    this.store.pipe(select(getSelectedMemberType(), {id: memberId}))
)
```

This will put the current value of the Observable inside `memberId`.

You can also convert the Observable into a Promise and await the value.

```js
const memberId = await this.store.pipe(
    select(getSelectedMemberType(), {id: memberId})
).toPromise()
```

You would have to declare the function `async` even though it can be accomplished synchronously with the first solution.

Comment: Thanks @Tobias S. I will leave this question open for a bit before I accept.

Comment: take note that takeOne will return undefined if your subscription has not emitted any values.

Comment: thats right, its only about taking a synchronous snapshot of the current state

Answer (score 0):

You can't have your method return the raw value (*output type of observable*).  You should instead have your function return `Observable<boolean>`:

```js
private checkMemberIsNotPremium(memberId): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.pipe(
        select(getSelectedMemberType(), {id: memberId}))
        map(val => val.membershipType !== 'Premium')
    );
  }
```

Notice you don't subscribe in the method, but have consumers subscribe to it to get the value.

Comment: This is the correct way, you need to shift your thinking to how observables work if you're going to use ngrx